# Lograge doesn't keep the original (and verbose) Rails logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm trying to use https://github.com/roidrage/lograge on a Rails 6.1 app

According to lograge README

[image]

I have configured it as follows

```
# config/production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
...

  config.log_level = :info
  config.lograge.keep_original_rails_log = true
  config.lograge.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new "#{Rails.root}/log/lograge_#{Rails.env}.log"
  config.lograge.custom_options = lambda { |event| { time: Time.now } }
end
```

However, nothing is logged to `lograge_production.log`.

```
bash-5.1$ cat lograge_production.log
# Logfile created on 2022-09-05 11:11:54 +0000 by logger.rb/v1.4.2
```

Even when there is a `fatal` error.

```
bash-5.1$ cat production.log
...
F, [2022-09-05T11:33:24.526190 #14] FATAL -- : [1f22ef13-99e0-4247-ad58-eea8d9255940]
[1f22ef13-99e0-4247-ad58-eea8d9255940] NoMethodError (undefined method `requires_article' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  require_or_load):
[1f22ef13-99e0-4247-ad58-eea8d9255940]
[1f22ef13-99e0-4247-ad58-eea8d9255940] app/models/operation.rb:21:in `block in <class:Operation>'
[1f22ef13-99e0-4247-ad58-eea8d9255940] app/controllers/operations_controller.rb:93:in `create'
bash-5.1$ ls
```

The issue is the same one described here https://github.com/roidrage/lograge/issues/298.

Am I missing anything?